# Charged Terminals of relay

Tags: relay

I'm reading a relay's [datasheet](http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5ca.pdf) from OMRON, it mentioned this

[image]

1. I haven't got the relay yet. So, what does 'charged terminals' mean?
2. I guess the shaded area may be where the coils located.
3. I think it mean the copper on *all layers*, which facing the shadow (not only the copper on the same layer with relay) should be removed, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on similar comments on an Omron datasheet for [relay sockets](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/G6B-4__ND.pdf), I think it's a reference to conductive metal that is connected - so a warning to not depend on the solder mask to insulate the bottom of the relay.

They are not suggesting that you remove copper from layers not facing the relay directly, though you may wish to do that for other reasons (to reduce capacitive coupling).

Comment: Thanks. You mean they are just metal may conductive (not the useful pins)? It's strange the G5CA-1A actually no such "terminals", http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1aBNLLXXXXXawXXXXq6xXFXXXI/OMRON-Relay-G5CA-1A-E-48VDC-G5CA-1A-E-48V-4pins-Max-switching-current-10A-PCB.jpg. Maybe others have. :)

Comment: What do you think routing some signal wires under relay, on the same side or on the opposite side? If the magnetic coil will do some bad?

Comment: I mean the metal is not floating. I would avoid routing signals under any relay, if possible, the contacts are a big potential noise source, maybe coil too.

Comment: Is it good or not to ground pour under the relay?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, in general.

Comment: It seems I've asked so many *other* questions under your answer, so I opened another page. Can you explain more there, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218676/how-about-ground-pouring-under-an-electromechanical-relay